# Visual Studio warning C4100 and TRACE

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In Visual Studio 2012, when I try to compile the following c++ function:

```
void CCustToolBar::OnCustHelp(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* /*pResult*/)
{
  TRACE(_T("{ Help ID = %d }\n"), pNMHDR->idFrom);
}
```

I get the warning "warning C4100: 'pNMHDR' : unreferenced formal parameter"

Which doesn't make sense, as pNMHDR is being used.  And if I try to comment it out:

```
void CCustToolBar::OnCustHelp(NMHDR* /*pNMHDR*/, LRESULT* /*pResult*/)
{
  TRACE(_T("{ Help ID = %d }\n"), pNMHDR->idFrom);
}
```

I get the error "error C2065: 'pNMHDR' : undeclared identifier"

Which does make sense.

What am I missing here?  Why am I getting warning C4100 when the variable is being used?

Comment: I could see it being unused if `TRACE` only happens in debug mode or something.

Comment: If that were the case, I would expect it to not complain when I try to build it in release with that variable commented out.

Comment: Trying adding `pNMHDR;` (this line does nothing). See [MSDN's article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26kb9fy0.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Yeah, I know how to get around it.  I am just curious about what's causing this.

Answer (score 1):

The MSDN page for [TRACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w95a4ha%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says:

> In the debug version of MFC, this macro sends the specified string to the debugger of the current application. In a release build, this macro compiles to nothing (no code is generated at all).

Therefore, you must be compiling in Release mode to get the warning, since the whole `TRACE` call will not exist in that configuration.

If you change your code to this:

```
void CCustToolBar::OnCustHelp(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* /*pResult*/)
{
  #ifdef DEBUG
    TRACE(_T("{ Help ID = %d }\n"), pNMHDR->idFrom);
  #else
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(pNMHDR);
  #endif
}
```

it would be a clean way to avoid the warning in Release mode while keeping the intended functionality for Debug.